# Converting byte[] to string

Tags: asp.net, byte

I have a `byte[]` and want to convert it to string in asp.net.
Here is my code:

```
for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < size; loop1++)
{
   displayString = displayString + input[loop1].ToString();
}
```

But this code takes too long, is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This will do all the work for you:

```
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);
```

Make sure the encoding you use is the correct one for the string array. See the MSDN reference of the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding_properties(v=vs.100).aspx) class to see all the encodings available.

Comment: Thanks,But I don't know which of them is good :( my input is :byte[]=input; and it is {byte[780831]}

Comment: Depends on the source, XML for example is usually UTF8. Just give it a try and see if the result is the expected one.

Comment: Yes...Unfortunately It didn't convert correctly :( .I uploaded a file(image) and need its byte[] in string,But this code that you told me makes incorrect string...

Comment: Can you be more precise on how it is incorrect?

Comment: when I use my code that I mentioned it in question my string is:8075342006080003302.....But when I use tour code it convert to :PK\0\0\b\0\0\0!\0�!�}�\0\0\0\0\0\b[Content_Types].xml �(�\0\0\0\0\0\0\

Comment: How did you encode it?

Comment: int size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] input = new byte[size - 1];string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);

Comment: Why `size-1`. Also, are you sure the content is right. The code provided should work.